# How to get response from cy.exec()

Tags: cypress

I am having hard time trying to get response from cy.exec() call.
For example:

```
cy.exec("java -version").then((response) => {
  cy.log("response is " + response);
});
```

The output I have is looking like this:

```
log response is [object Object]
```

What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cy.exec()` yields an object with the following properties:

1. code
2. stdout
3. stderr

So to get the java version you have to log the `stderr` property

```js
cy.exec("java -version").then((result) => {
    cy.log(result.stderr);
  })
```

Test Runner Screenshot showing Java version:

[image: test runner screenshot]

Comment: Thank you! It was really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In the [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/exec#Yields)

> cy.exec() yields an object with the following properties:
>
> - code
> - stdout
> - stderr

So for your particular execution string, the response is probably on `stdout`

```js
cy.exec("java -version").then((response) => {
  cy.log("response is " + response.stdout);
})
```

Comment: You can use `.its('stdout')` before the `.then()` block so you can use `cy.log` only.